# Making nodejs application run on 0.0.0.0 rather than on localhost

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run this app https://github.com/nheidloff/conversation-optimizer-for-ibm-watson It is running only on 127.0.0.1

```
# netstat -plnt                    │
Active Internet connections (only servers)                                                                  │
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name            │
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      411/node
```

How do I make it run on 0.0.0.0? I tried reading the code but since I am not a programmer I am unable to makeout what to change so posting the git URL above.

Comment: You have to change it in webpack config or specify the HOST argument in your start script.

Comment: The start script is https://github.com/nheidloff/conversation-optimizer-for-ibm-watson/blob/master/node/server-local.js Where and in what format should I put the HOST argument?

Comment: Assuming you're on linux: `HOST='0.0.0.0' npm run server`

Answer (score 2):

This is in `/config/webpack.prod.js`:

```
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
```

and this is in `/config/webpack.dev.js`:

```
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

So if it is usinf localhost instead of 0.0.0.0, the app is using production config. To set it to use development config, run:
`webpack --env dev`

Comment: @Siju George does this help?

Comment: I am unable to use webpack because there are dependency problems in installing webpack-dev-server. I run it with the following commands. # cd conversation-optimizer-for-ibm-watson
# npm install
# typings install
# npm run build:prod
# cd node
# npm install
# node server-local.js